# Sorting Level Data by Two properties when One or More Values are the Same

Tags: discord, discord.js, leaderboard

I am having some trouble sorting data by two parameters for a leaderboard command on a Discord.js bot. I currently have it where the users are sorted by level.
The only issue with this is that when there are two users with the same level, it needs to be sorted by whoever has the most XP:

Example:
User1: Lvl 20; 50/200XP
 User2: Lvl 20; 80/200XP
User2 should show up before User 1

I've been trying various solutions I found, but none have solved the problem, any help on this is much appreciated, thank you!

Level data & XP Data Stored here:

```js
  let level = db.all().filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`guild_646074330249429012_level`)).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data)


  let userXP = db.all().filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`guild_646074330249429012_xp`)).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data)
```

Comment: Would not sorting by just XP get you the result you want? Since Lvl is based on XP, sorting by XP sorts both.

Comment: That's what I thought before as well, but I realized that when a user levels up, their xp resets. So, say for instance someone is level 30 with 800/1000 XP, and another user is level 31 with 8/1500 XP. The level 30 user would be before the level 31 user, simply because their current XP is higher, although their level is lower

Comment: Ah, okay, it wasn't clear in your question that XP isn't cumulative. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes my answer uses Math.pow to prevent that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
leaderboard.sort((b, a) => ((a.rank+1)*(a.xp)) - (Math.pow((b.rank+1), 10)*(b.xp)))
//replace leaderboard with whatever array has all the ranks and xps
//also, idk how to get rank and xp from your code so I just did .rank and .xp
```

This way, you sort everything at once

Comment: I'll give this a shot, not too sure how to configure it with my data, but It's worth trying it out, appreciate it

Comment: Please mark this as accepted if it helped! Also, whatever variable ranks and xp are stored in, replace the a.rank, b.rank, a.xp and b.xp with that!